Adjusting plot and axis labels on Likert Scale
I am trying to adjust my Likert plot to allow my y-axis labels to fit on one line as opposed to being cut off into two lines as show here.
I am using the following code:
 plot_usability <- likert.bar.plot(usability_summary, group.order=c
    ("1. The eOrdering system was easy to learn",
     "2. When I need help on an order entry, I can find it",
     "3. The eOrdering system is reliable and easy to use",
     "4. Overall, I am satisfied with the eOrdering system")) +
    ggtitle("Usability") +
    theme(text = element_text(size = rel(4)), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(2)), legend.position = "right") +
    theme_update(legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.7))) +
    theme_classic()
   print(plot_usability)


Any ideas how I can adjust the margins of plot to allow the y-axis labels (questions) to fit on one line?
I have added adjustments to margins using mar(par) command but it hasn't worked.  I am hoping to find code that will allow me to make this subtle change so that the full questions are one line, instead of the last word or two being cut off and placed on second line.
